# Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server - Server 2016

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, sqlsrv

I am using PHP 5.6.35, and I have downloaded and installed/enabled the Microsoft SQL Server Drivers for PHP.  Specifically, the ones below

> extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
>   extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll

I can see that they are enabled properly looking at the phpinfo() output.  It shows both pdo_sqlsrv as enabled as well as sqlsrv support.  However, when I try to connect to my database I get the following error back.

> This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server.
>   Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server
>   for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no
>   default driver specified [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]
>   Data source name not found and no default driver specified )

So, I assumed I needed to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server.  So I downloaded what I thought was the correct file from here.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434

But when I try to install the driver I get an error stating that the installation of this product failed because it is not supported on this operating system.  I'm running PHP 5.6.35 on Windows Server 2016.

HELP?

Comment: That page clearly shows the system requirements and Server 2016 is not in the list. **Supported Operating System

Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2012, Windows Vista Service Pack 2**

Comment: @Dave, I have seen that, however what I need is a version of the driver that DOES support Server 2016.  Is there one?

Comment: Try the [ODBC Driver 13.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53339) which does include Server 2016 in the supported systems list

Comment: @Dave, tried it, but once on the download page again it says the Supported Operating Systems stop at 2012 R2.

Comment: Makes no sense. That is the page linked to from the MS developers who said it was the version to use with Server 2016. And Server 2016 is specifically mentioned in the supported operating systems on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the x64 install file. I ran into the same issue and was able to add the 32 bit driver from the x64 installation. I have a 64 bit processors and I tried to test the 32 bit install file for implementation on the x86 systems and seen the same error.